# Failed to connect node.js app to MongoDB Atlas despite using the correct connection credentials

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect my node.js application to MongoDB Atlas but I keep getting a "Bad authentication error" and yes, I am using the current database user credentials.
Here is the snippet that's supposed to connect to MongoDB Atlas

```
const connectDB = async () => {
try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
    })

    console.log('MongoDB Connected: ' +conn.Connection.host)
}catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
}
```

}

My terminate shows me bad authentication and some key-pairs that look so:

```
{
```

ok: 0,
code: 8000,
codeName: 'AtlasError',
name: 'MongoError'
}

Any ideas why it is not connecting to MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: The password use @ or space?

Comment: I solved the problem. The issue was, I replacing the password  section in the database connection string inside the <password> without removing the  angle brackets "<" & ">"

Answer (score 1):

I finally singled out the problem, it was the MongoDB connection string. I was simply inserting my password in the password field  without removing the angle brackets.